# AJAX and IE using jquery GET, receive no response

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I have a problem trying to make a ajax GET request. I need to figure out how to transform my jquery to the original method using XDR. Here is my code. and here is what I want to add. I know where to add it, I just dont know how or where to place all my variables. So heres what I have :

```
$.post("post.php?"+$("#MYFORM").serialize(), {

        }, function(response){

            if(response==1 && codeVal == 1 && telVal == 1)
            {
                $("#after_submit").html('');
                $("#Send").after('<label class="success" id="after_submit">Η αποστολή πραγματοποιήθηκε</label>');
                change_captcha();
                clear_form();
                $.ajax({
                        type:'GET',
                        cache: false,
                        url: "web.something.gr/submit_code.php",
                        data:{ user: "123456", pass: "123456", source: "WEB", receipt: num, msisdn: phone},
                        success: function(data) { 
                            var qsFull = "web.something.gr/submit_code.php?" + data;
                            var qs = URI(qsFull).query(true);
                            TINY.box.show({html:qs.message,animate:false,boxid:'error',top:5});
                        },
                        error: function(data) {
                                    var qsFull = "web.mobilemedia.gr/input/microsoft/submit_code.php?" + data;
                                    var qs = URI(qsFull).query(true);
                                    TINY.box.show({html:qs.message,animate:false,boxid:'error',top:5});
                        }
                    });
            }
            else
            {
                $("#after_submit").html('');
                $("#Send").after('<label class="error" id="after_submit">Error! in CAPTCHA .</label>');
            }
        });
```

This works in all browsers except IE.. so I want to fit this in there, but dont know how:

```
if ($.browser.msie && window.XDomainRequest) {
            // Use Microsoft XDR
            var xdr = new XDomainRequest();
            xdr.open("get", "someurl");
            xdr.onload = function () {
            var JSON = $.parseJSON(xdr.responseText);
            if (JSON == null || typeof (JSON) == 'undefined')
            {
                JSON = $.parseJSON(data.firstChild.textContent);
            }
            processData(JSON);
            };
            xdr.send();
        }
```

And I dont really think I use JSON, just text/html so What is my next step to make this happen. Becuase I have this working on every other browser.. Is it a syntax error, Do I really need this If statement? Please help.

Comment: I found the answer to this. See this link: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13633661/ie-not-reading-get-success-after-post

Answer (score 0):

Apply this code clause; "data.firstChild.textContent" doesn't work in IE

```
 if(isIE() && isIE() < 10) {                
 JSON = $.parseJSON(data.text); }

function isIE() {
var myNav = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
return (myNav.indexOf('msie') != -1) ? parseInt(myNav.split('msie')[1]) : false;}
```